# Get value from django field and change it dynamically

Tags: django

I have created  two models with two fields which are quantity and quantity_given, so I want to change the value of quantity field by adding the value of quantity + quantity given. For example
if quantity = 4 and quantity_given = 8
therefore the new value of quantity field will be 12.

Here are the source code for my models

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    `name = models.CharField(max_length=30)`

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Medicine(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MedicineGiven(models.Model):
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_given = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a method in *MedicineGiven*, like:

```
class MedicineGiven(models.Model):
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_given = models.IntegerField()
 
    @property
    def quantity(self):
        return self.quantity_given + int(self.medicine.quantity)
```

In your views, you can get quantity of *MedicineGiven* like:

```
medicine_given = MedicineGiven.objects.get(pk=id) # Just a example code
medicine_given.quantity
```

### EDIT

If you want to save the *quantity* in database, then you can override `save()` method:

```
class MedicineGiven(models.Model):
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_given = models.IntegerField()
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        quantity = self.quantity_given + int(self.medicine.quantity)  

        self.medicine.quantity = quantity
        self.medicine.save()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond but  I want to save the quantity_given + int(self.medicine.quantity) to quantity field

Comment: To which quantity field in `MedicineGiven`?

Comment: @AliyuAssalafiyGama Updated the post. Have a glance!!!

Comment: No, the quantity field in Medicine

Comment: @AliyuAssalafiyGama Have a look again.

Comment: thank @Biplove Lamichhane it has worked well now. I'm really appreciated